# Jw player not playing advertisements on reload of page

Tags: node.js, jwplayer

I am trying play ad videos before any video playing. When I refresh the page or if i try to play same video again that ad video not coming. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, JW player playing advertisements after every 2 min. We can schedule adverisements in jw player.
For example:

```
   jwplayer("myElement").setup({
     "file": "*http://example.com/myVideo.mp4*",
     "advertising": {
       "client": "vast",
       "schedule": "myvmap.xml"
       }
   });
```